# In Processing language real time control

Tags: processing, real-time

How can I do the following:
I have an animation that is tapping every second and you can hear every beat.
I want to press the spacebar at the same time and if we are not in sync (tapping simultaneously) then make anything (error or something else)...
Is this possible?
can you suggest me how to do it?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `millis()` function to help with timing calculations. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html).

Basically, what you'd want to do is store two times: store the time the sound is played, and store the time the player presses the key. Then just subtract them to get the difference. Something like this:

```java
int keyTime = -1;
int soundTime = -1;

void keyPressed(){
   keyTime = millis();
}

void playSound(){
   soundTime = millis();
}

void checkDifference(){
   if(keyTime > -1 && soundTime > -1){
      int difference = keyTime - soundTime;
      //do something with difference
   }
}
```

This is just example code, but the idea is there: just use the `millis()` function to record the time of each event, and then use subtraction to get the difference.